# How to calculate closest total price from item prices collection with multiple items

Tags: mongodb, scala, stream, permutation

Given a set of prices from a provider I want to work out the closest matching item set that will match a total value.

IE. The total value to match is $5, I have a price list from MongoDB as follows

```scala
val items = List(0.05, 0.06, 1.0, 2.0)
```

How do I work out the set of items that will give $5? The items can be duplicated in order to match the price.

My idea is to use a Stream to evaluate the price list and create permutations and match with an accuracy of $0.01 but I do not know how to go about doing that?

The other idea is to write an aggregation from MongoDB to provide the permutations and then sort by total price and pick the closest one

UPDATE:

So I am now sampling products from the database using the following:

```js
db.getCollection("shop-items").aggregate([
    {
        $bucketAuto: {
              groupBy: "$prices.avg",
              buckets: 50,
              output: {
                "items" : {
                    $push: "$$ROOT"
                },
               "count": { $sum: 1 },
              }
          }
    },
    {$addFields: {"startField": {$floor :{$multiply: [ { $rand: {} }, "$count"]}}}},
    {$project : { _id: 0, items: {$slice: ["$items", "$startField", 20]}}},
    {$unwind: "$items"}
])
```

This results in about `650` items which will still result in `650!` permutations which I would need to calculate

Comment: I want the least amount of items possible, right now i am working on a database optimization to reduce the permutation count but I assume using `.permutations` on a LazyList can do the trick however a LazyList is not sorted and I do not understand in what order the permutations are created

Comment: @jwvh if there is a tie or such I can take either so I want the first to match the price

Comment: I attempted [this](https://gist.github.com/DiscworldZA/b6b17fe5496f3a363c258ada76881c27) however this loads all 5000! permutations into memory, I might have made a mistake on the code?

Answer (score 0):

This is an algorithm question. Using a DB to generate permutations doesn't sound efficient. What you are looking for is a [Knapsack solution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem) with memoization. Basically, you need to solve `ar(n) = minimum number items to get total sum n (with buffer of $0.01, if needed)`. The algorithm sketch will be:

```
Memoized array ar[500], where ar[y] = minimum number of items to match $(y/100).
All elements are initalized to infinite/very large value.

val items = [5, 6, 100, 200]

Initialize / populate: ar[0] = 0; items.forEach(ar[_] = 1);

while ($ar[500] is not populated) {
  for (y where ar[y] is populated) {
     items.forEach( item => ar[y + item] = min(ar[y + item], ar[y] + 1);
  }
}
```

This will result in upper bound complexity of O(n * m) where n is the total number of possible outcomes (here 500), and m is total number of distinct items-prices, probably a constant.